# how to user color from global resources?

Tags: xaml, colors, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I want to set my resources on the app.xaml and then use it in the differents views of the app, but when I set the color the app crashes u.u, could someone help me ?

app.xaml

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Primary">#FFC107</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

use it in a StackLayout

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">
```

Comment: `Style` would expect a `StyleTemplate` as its resource. Are you just wanting instead; `<StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" ..../>`

Comment: yes, but it is not working in that mode

Comment: Mode? Does it maybe want a resource of type `Brush` instead of type `Color`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has you called InitializeComponent in the App.xaml.cs?

Comment: Many thanks that was the missing part. it is working now!! (Y)

Answer (score 3):

you need to use Static Resource,I find a good resource for you:

https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/

So you need to do the following:

1- Define a `ResourceDictionary` at the app-level in App.xaml

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MonkeyTweet.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="backgroundColor">#33302E</Color>
            <Color x:Key="textColor">White</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

2- Use StaticResource markup extension to reference predefined resources:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor = "{StaticResource textColor}"/>
```

Comment: so, i think the problem not come from this issue

Comment: if I use StaticResource my app crashes!!

Comment: try to use it from code behind, and check on which line error occured

Comment: Why Application.Current.Resources is null ? am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

```
BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Primary}"
```

its a DynamicResource, not a StaticResource.

Here's what my code looks like for example:

App.xaml has

```
<Color x:Key="titleColor">Green</Color>
```

and a page.xaml has

```
TextColor="{DynamicResource titleColor}"
```

Comment: using DynamicResource won't crash my app, but it doesn't apply the color to the background of my stackLayout.

Comment: @AlexanderRojas, odd, I'm using that throughout my app, I have global styles applied to certain layouts and controls too. At this point I can only think to check what "farid JAD7" suggests about calling InitializeComponent in the code behind.
`  public App() {
   InitializeComponent(); // to load the global styles`